# Four product of sphrerical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

I encounter four product of sphrerical harmonic problems and found it has this equation

$Y_{l_1}^{m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2}^{m_2}(\theta,\phi) =$

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{l,m}\sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l+1)}{4\pi}} \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} } \right) \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l  \\ m_1 & m_2 & m  \\ \end{array} } \right)(-1)^m Y_{l}^{m}(\theta,\phi)$

and then I apply to be this equation

$\int Y_{l_1}^{m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2}^{m_2}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_3}^{m_3}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_4}^{m_4}(\theta,\phi)\ d\Omega = $

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{l_{12},m_{12}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(2l_1+1\right)\left(2l_2+1\right)\left(2l_3+1\right)\left(2l_4+1\right)\left(2l_{12}+1\right){}^2}{4\pi }} \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_{12}  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} } \right) \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_{12}  \\ m_1 & m_2 & m_{12}  \\ \end{array} } \right)$

$\left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_3 & l_4 & l_{12}  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} } \right) \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_3 & l_4 & l_{12}  \\ m_3 & m_4 & -m_{12}  \\ \end{array} } \right)$

Any one can tell me that I am correct ?

Comment: This appears off-topic as it is about mathematics and not physics.

Comment: Is this about 3j and 6j symbols? I think I saw a similar post on math.SE but I cannot find it...

Comment: @KyleKanos I encounter this in my particle physics thesis and forget about it is a mathematics. I will post on math.SE

Comment: @dingo_d thank you I will find it.